# UITableView scroll at top issue iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a tableview and I would like to know when user scroll at top and if in those moment the tableview is not at top (for example its at middle) I just implement the delegate method `scrollViewDidScroll` and check the value of content offset and its ok.

My problem is when the tableview is is already at the top and `scrollViewDidScroll` is not called (I want to know if the user do the gesture for scroll to the top even if it is already at the top).

For this reason I thought to add a pan gesture to tableview but I saw that create problems about scrolling and the implementation is cumbersome.

I ask to you if you know another way to achieve this or the only way is adding pan gesture.

Comment: You should try to use scrollViewWillBeginDragging or scrollViewWillEndDragging

Comment: You should review the documentation for `UIScrollView scrollsToTop`.

Comment: @JohnnyAW thanks it work. how do I vote your answer?

Comment: @Arturi it was a comment, I posted it as an answer, so you can vote for it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to use `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` or `scrollViewWillEndDragging`